# Error in python with VS Code - Import <filename> could not be resolved

Tags: python

Question about this error, hopefully someone can help.

First - my code works fine

Second, this was my original code;

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from axlAuth import client
```

So, when I got my code to work properly I started moving files into directories that made more sense as I started to add more pieces.  axlAuth is now in another directory, auth.  But to get this to work, I need to add a path.  So, now my code is this;

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
sys.path.append("./auth")
from axlAuth import client
```

It works fine, and of course I'm adding a reference to the previous level's auth to get to axlAuth.  But now I'm getting a pylance error;

```
Error in python with VS Code - Import axlAuth could not be resolved
```

The recommendations that I've found to resolve the issue have basically been;

- add "./axlAuth" to extrapaths

  - This adds a new directory ".vscode" and adds a json file that resolves the directory

I'd like to avoid this, I'm sure there's a smarter way to do this.  How do you reference a file in another folder to import objects without creating an error like this?

Comment: vs code has the capability to add extra directories for imports.  Use that.